# Several headings inside <nav>

Tags: seo, html5

We use a fat layer navigation which partly consists of content that some CMS users insert with a rich text editor (TYPO3 is the CMS btw).

By this we have several `<hX>` tags inside the `<nav>` tag which contains the navigational layer.

Now a SEO agency tells us that this is bad.

I searched the internet and the few answer I got are contradictory.

**Are there any facts that say bad or not?**

The real code is not insteresting from my POV. But here is an abbreviated example: jsfiddle.net/5Ldjvytr

Comment: I would have to see a sample. Can you give us a sample??

Comment: @closetnoc The code is not that important, I think. It's just the fact that we have `<h1>` inside `<nav>`. Here is a abbreviated example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ldjvytr/

Comment: Are you interested in SEO *only*?

Comment: Yes. I want to know if this has any negative impact on SEO

Comment: I am rather agreeing with @TheAlbear. I would think that the header tags dilute your potential. Google seems to favor navigational links anyway so using a header tag serves no purpose that I can see. I have always believed that header tags should be used to indicate the topic and sub-topics in a cascading fashion taking advantage of your most important keywords and other important keywords in lesser header tags. Using header tags for navigation would dilute this effect and potentially cause unimportant keywords to rank off-topic.

Comment: Most search engines aren't going to use a HTML5 parser and will just see multiple H1's. That said, I've never seen a site where this would cause any noticable change, I wouldn't be pedantic about "only one H1/page" for SEO purposes if you have good reasons to use that markup.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule I wouldn't have a H1/HX in the document `<nav` or anywhere in a repeated part of the page as it will then mean that every page has some of the same heading.

If there are multiple H1's then you SEO juice will be split between them all, when what you want is each page to have its own unique headings relevant to that pages content.

More informatin can be found http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/how-to-use-heading-tags-for-seo/